# Can't compile external template

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs-directive, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I decided to make my template external, since it became too big and there is no markup.
So i created .html file and typed path to it inside my directive instead of internal template:

```
templateUrl = root + 'App/modules/blanks/common/Templates/requestBlanks.tpl.html';
```

It works, but my karma-jasmine test started to fail since they cannot achieve it when trying to perform $compile
I installed https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor and performed

App/modules/blanks/common/Templates/requestBlanks.tpl.html

```
<div>
... some html with angular
</div>
```

karma.conf.js

```
...
files: [
 //== Templates
  'App/**/*.tpl.html',
...
preprocessors: {
            'App/**/*.tpl.html': ['ng-html2js']
        },

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            moduleName: 'myTemplates'
        },
...
```

requestBlanks-directive.spec.js

```
'use strict';

describe('directive: requestBlanks', function () {

    var $compile,
        $rootScope;
    beforeEach(module(
        'myTemplates',
        App.Modules.Blanks.moduleId));


    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));



    it('tag should be compiled by angular', function() {
        var element = $compile('<div data-request-blanks data-ng-model="blankType.data"></div>')($rootScope);
        expect(element.html()).not.toBe('');
    });
```

But i got error:

```
Expected '' not to be ''.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Adding  `prependPrefix: root,` didn't helped. But the problem is definitely in path

Answer (score 0):

defining root by adding `var root = '';` in conf file helped